# PHP corrupt file upload

Tags: php

I'm trying to let users upload files onto my website, but unfortunately some of them seem to turn corrupt when reading them. I've tried both images and html files, and all the images come through corrupt (the HTML files come through fine).

To upload the files I'm using a standard HTML form and the PHP $_FILES array. I'm then using the following code to read the contents of the file:

> $filename = $_FILES['varname']['tmp_name'];
>
> $handle = fopen($filename, "r");`
>
> $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
>
> fclose($handle);

Unfortunately the value of $contents is now slightly different to the file I uploaded (here's a snippet from the top of the file):

**Original file:**

> ˇÿˇ·ExifII*ˇÏDucky<ˇÓAdobed¿ˇ€Ñ

**New file:**

> ˇÿˇ· Exif  II*            ˇÏ Ducky     <  ˇÓ Adobe d¿   ˇ€ Ñ

As you can see there's a difference in the spacing. Any ideas what would be causing this? Am I handling the file read incorrectly for binary files? It seems odd that it's fine for any text files I upload..

Thanks!

Comment: hey, I know it is too late but do you got any idea why this was happening because I am started to get the same problem while uploading images to my server, some images upload fine some get corrupt like replacing some character at some position by space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you print $contents ? Are you sure this is a problem with reading the file ?

I guess that maybe this is a problem with PRINTING the file to the output... Try printing it binary way. Something like:

```
$data = unpack("C*", $contents);    
foreach ($data as $v)
{
   echo $v, ' ';
}
```

and compare that with binary dump of the original file...

Comment: That's produced a load of numbers so I'll do a comparison of that shortly. Unfortunately I'm not actually outputting the file.. the variable $contents gets pushed into a 3rd party system (that's fine with files coming from other systems), so it's difficult to debug where it's all going wrong!

Answer (score 2):

I usually output files like this:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");    
readfile("$HOME_DIR/uploads/$fileName");
exit();
```

Anyway, to try to debug your problem, you should first understand which phase is failing. Upload or download? To check, just go to your webserver and download the file via FTP, then open it in a binary editor. If it is already corrupt then you need to investigate your upload phase, otherwise it's the other way around.